# How to use RxJava ReplaySubject<object> to emit object in define interval

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have custom set of objects that's I want to emit after every 2 seconds.That means when I add set Of Items to ReplaySubject<> it should get access to those object **one by one** `onNext()` method every 2 seconds. This objects are added to ReplaySubject<> dynamically on user events. That's why I'm using ReplaySubject<>.

I have achieve that but I want to pause and resume this thread 
base on some condition which is going to be change base on a user interaction. How to achieve this.

Here's my code.

```
private ReplaySubject<CartItemToBeRemove> cartItemToBeRemoveSubject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        cartItemToBeRemoveSubject = ReplaySubject.create();

        initDeleteQueue();
    }

public void initDeleteQueue() {

        cartItemToBeRemoveSubject
                .delay(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new Observer<CartItemToBeRemove>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(CartItemToBeRemove itemToBeRemove) {
                        cartData.remove(itemToBeRemove.getItem());
                        cartListAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(itemToBeRemove.getPosition());
                        Log.d(TAG, "item" + deletedItem.getName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
    }
```

I'm adding objects to ReplaySubject like below

```
cartItemToBeRemoveSubject.onNext(toBeRemove);
```

Comment: I don't have a definite answer for you, but you might look at `zip`ping your subject with an `Observable.interval`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add pacing to an observable stream. Normal pacing is emitting an item once every two seconds, but that may be paused and resumed.

The basic pacing mechanism is something like `Observable.interval( 2, SECONDS )`, which emits a `Long` every 2 seconds. However, you want to be able pause it occasionally. Let's say we have an `Observable<Boolean>` that emits `TRUE` when the pacing mechanism is to proceed and `FALSE` when it should pause.

```
Observable<Boolean> pacingControl;

pacingControl
  .switchMap( ctl -> ctl ? Observable.interval( 0, 2, SECONDS ) : Observable.never() )
  .zipWith( cartItemToBeRemoveSubject, (t, item) -> item )
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe( ... );
```

`pacingControl` can be implemented as a subject and the user action will be either `pacingControl.onNext( TRUE )` to start the process or `pacingControl.onNext( FALSE )` to pause it. The `switchMap()` operator switches between the timer and `never()`, which obviously never produces anything.